# No Access to Template's Document

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word

I have an existing Macro Enabled Template which I would like to add Content Control to, to be available on the screen when the Template is accessed.

I know how to add the Content to a Word Document and then save it as a Template. The problem is that I cannot view the Exisiting Template's Word Document due to the `view Object` being greyed out. See below:

[image]

I really do not want to copy all my Macros and my quick texts over to a new document just to add one line of text and a button.

I can easily add the required text and `CommandButton` by having a script run in a `Document_New` Sub under the `ThisDocument`. The problem is that this Sub bombs out due to Macros not being enabled. I intend to have the Template distributed to numerous colleagues, therefore having the Text and button on the document will avoid any confusion as to what to do with the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the Template via  File -  Open

Opening the Template this way will display give you access to the Template.

For info: The name of the Template will appear in the Center of the Word Application.